# Do I need a comma after landscaper?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

During my college years, I worked as a landscaper becoming increasingly drawn to the wild plants and their uses in folk medicine.

Comment: No, the comma is not strictly needed there, but, at any rate, be aware that there are no precise rules about punctuation.

Comment: Thank you, Carlo and thank you everybody for the other posts which I just saw. I was looking at the negative votes only and not scrolling down. Sorry for not reading the rules.

Comment: I wouldn't like to say it's actually "wrong" to use a comma here - as Carlo says, there are no precise rules. But in practice I doubt 1 in 100 writers would include it. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Ren, don't worry and be aware that the linguistic structure of written languages is qualitatively identical to that of spoken language and, mostly, the connection is founded on punctuation--which, as is well known, represents spoken-language intonation. I hope this help.

Comment: It seems very awkward to me without a comma.

Comment: I agree with @DavidSchwartz -- I think a comma is highly desirable here (if not strictly necessary).

Answer (score 1):

I think a comma here is highly desirable, if not strictly necessary from a grammatical point of view.  The difference is that "becoming increasingly drawn to the wild plants and their uses in folk medicine" is a adding extra information, not qualifying "landscaper" (that is to say, this clause does not answer the question "what kind of lanscaper?").  In speech, a brief pause would be necessary here, and I would add the comma to indicate this (as @Carlo_R has commented).